# CakePHP validation notEmpty does not take TAB

Tags: validation, cakephp

I have validation on my model that is notEmpty.

However, sometimes my value needs to be TAB. Cake takes tab as empty.

What are possible solutions around this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You could go with the [Regular Expression validation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#custom-regular-expression-validation) to define yourself what is allowed or not.